# toUpperCaseLocale() vs toUpperCase() - Now targeting Android 4.2

Tags: android

Since I targeted a newer SDK version of Android, I have been getting a warning on this line of code:

```
return getString(R.string.usertab1).toUpperCase()
```

When I hover over it, it says:

> Implicitly using the default locale is a common source of bugs: Use `toUpperCase(Locale)` instead.

Does anyone know how to remove this error? And why is it now a preferred way to use this method?

I get this is the answer, to use `toUpperCase(Locale)` but having trouble implementing it.  Where does the `Locale` object come from?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could *explicitly* use the default locale:

```
return getString(R.string.usertab1).toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
```

Basically, you don't want to *implicitly* allow the device to use the default, because this can mean you simply ignored the fact that it could be an issue. For machine-readable content, you may want to specify a specific locale (such as `Locale.ENGLISH`) to ensure you always get the reusability you want out of the data. For showing the user, explicitly specifying the default locale should be fine.

For a more complete read:

> A common mistake is to implicitly use the default locale when producing output meant to be machine-readable. This tends to work on the developer's test devices (especially because so many developers use en_US), but fails when run on a device whose user is in a more complex locale.
>
> For example, if you're formatting integers some locales will use non-ASCII decimal digits. As another example, if you're formatting floating-point numbers some locales will use `','` as the decimal point and `'.'` for digit grouping. That's correct for human-readable output, but likely to cause problems if presented to another computer (`parseDouble(String)` can't parse such a number, for example). You should also be wary of the `toLowerCase()` and `toUpperCase()` overloads that don't take a Locale: in Turkey, for example, the characters `'i'` and `'I'` won't be converted to `'I'` and `'i'`. This is the correct behavior for Turkish text (such as user input), but inappropriate for, say, HTTP headers.
>
> -- [`Locale` developer documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html)

Comment: A better place to get this is from the Configuration object, which you can obtain from any `Context` using `getResources().getConfiguration()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#locale

Comment: I have the same problem.My characters are Turkish but I couldnt see something like this "Locale.TURKISH" How can I handle this ?

Comment: @GünayGültekin You can use `new Locale("tr_TR")`: [**Click here for a sample**](http://ideone.com/IavMuX)

Comment: I had to Project/Clean... to get rid of the warning after changing to `.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)`.

Comment: Even that doesn't always help. For me the warning came back after a week. I don't really think we can do anything about it other than ignoring it.